# Google cloud storage viewer upload not working

Tags: google-cloud-storage

i have been using the storge console https://storage.cloud.google.com for months now and all working well.

I just received a message indicating that the storage console is deprecated in favour of the storage viewer. https://cloud.google.com/console

the new cloud storage viewer is not working in sarfari 5.1.7.
the upload button is not working, i am unable to upload.
there are no error just nothing happens.

any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

For the file upload to work, I think you will need to use Firefox, Chrome, or upgrade to Safari 6.

Comment: safari 6 not available on windows but FF/chrome are all good. thanks